# WPF Toolkit LineSeries Chart display X axis label at 45 angle and every third one

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a line chart using the WPF Toolkit with two ploted lines. The chart will display the last 30 days and to make the X axis label easier to read I would like to turn the labels to a 45 degree angle and display every third one. I'm having issues with the label angle and displaying every third one.

Code example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    Title="Chart Samples" Height="600" Width="1025">
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<DVC:Chart Grid.Row="0" Name="HphChart2" Width="400" Height="250" LegendTitle="Roads" Title="Line Series HPH Roads Per Day" Padding="1">
  <DVC:Chart.Axes>
      <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Horse Power Hours" Background="Linen"/>
      <DVC:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="Days" />
  </DVC:Chart.Axes>

  <DVC:Chart.Series>
      <!-- Road 1 -->
      <DVC:LineSeries Title="Rd-1"
                      IndependentValuePath="Key"
                      DependentValuePath="Value"
                      ToolTip="Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX">
          <DVC:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
              <Style TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"/>
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
              </Style>
          </DVC:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
      </DVC:LineSeries>

      <!-- Road 2 -->
      <DVC:LineSeries Title="Rd-2"
                      IndependentValuePath="Key"
                      DependentValuePath="Value" >
          <DVC:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
              <Style TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
              </Style>
          </DVC:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
      </DVC:LineSeries>
   </DVC:Chart.Series>

</DVC:Chart>
</Grid>
</Window>

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadAreaChartData();
}

private void LoadAreaChartData()
{
    //Road 1
    ((LineSeries)HphChart2.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("01/29/14", 100),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("01/30/14", 180),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("01/31/14", 110),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("02/01/14", 95),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("02/02/14", 40),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("02/03/14", 95)
        };

    //Road 2
    ((LineSeries)HphChart2.Series[1]).ItemsSource =
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("01/29/14", 150),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("01/30/14", 100),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("01/31/14", 80),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("02/01/14", 95),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("02/02/14", 90),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("02/03/14", 190)
        };
}
```